# Input field is not recognizing pasted data

Tags: angularjs

i have a problem that, when i try to copy paste the data, it is not recognized by Angular. But if i just delete the last number and write it again, then it is recognized. Any ideas what can cause that ?

```
<input limit-to="20" name="iban"  class="form-control" ng-model="paymentData.iban" placeholder="AT1234567890123456789"
                   iban="DE" required,
                   xt-validation-tooltip placement="top"
                   msg-iban="Bitte geben Sie eine gültige IBAN ein."
                   msg-required="Bitte geben Sie Ihre IBAN ein."/>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say its not recognized by angular? I see you have an orphaned div. Is your input sandwiched within a div wired to a controller?
Play with this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abidmix/47Lyt9av/) and see that everything works as expected even for copied and pasted numbers.

**Markup**

```
<div  ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input limit-to="20" name="iban"  class="form-control" ng-model="paymentData.iban" placeholder="AT234567890123456789"
               iban="DE" required,
               xt-validation-tooltip placement="top"
               msg-iban="Bitte geben Sie eine gültige IBAN ein."
               msg-required="Bitte geben Sie Ihre IBAN ein."/>

               {{paymentData.iban}}

 </div>
```

**JS**

```
     var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]).
     controller('MyCtrl',function MyCtrl($scope) {

      });
```